# Fabric doesn't upload app when app id contain `-`?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have an iOS app with have app id `com.enterprise.test-qa` (not real name)
which cannot get upload and create a new app in fabric dashboard

However, when I try changing it to `com.enterprise.testqa` it got upload successfully and a new app appear with `com.enterprise.testqa` appear in the dashboard.

Is this a limitation on fabric?
How can I get my app with `-` inside app id to be added to fabric?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Having the dash shouldn't be causing any issue. Try enabling debug mode - https://docs.fabric.io/apple/fabric/advanced-settings/debugging.html - , do a build and run with Fabric enabled on both and see if that gets the app activated.

Comment: I see everything see along the line `settings downloaded successfully`, `Starting onboarding with app update`, `completed application update`. And looking into build log, Run script for fabric also have green checkbox in front which should indicate success. But the app still does not appear in Fabric when I search.

Comment: Actually doing some further investigation, I also try changing it to `com.enterprise.test-qa12345` which somehow happen to work!!!. Now I starting to think the app-id that I use maybe collide with some other people?

For that appid we have it in our apple portal but seem like for fabric it can be any string without the need to have actual appid on apple portal

Comment: Very odd, but glad you're all set. Yes, the bundle id or package name can be any value, it doesn't need to match Apple or Google's developer portals.

Comment: Can this be solved? I mean I still cannot use that app id? the first one that I want. It is an appid from our customer and I don't think we can change that.

Comment: Ahh, email into support(at)fabric(dot)io with the package name of the app and they can see what can be done to fix things up.